# Empty DataFrame Output Using Telsa Option Data

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to graph the put-call parity relationship using Telsa stock options.

I am coming up with a blank graphic which means I must have a blank dataframe?

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

TSLA = web.YahooOptions('TSLA')
TSLA.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Firefox'}

alloptions = TSLA.get_all_data()
alloptions.reset_index(inplace=True)

exp1 = alloptions[alloptions.Expiry == TSLA.expiry_dates[1]]

calls = exp1[exp1.Type=='call']
calls['C'] = (calls.Bid+calls.Ask)/2
puts = exp1[exp1.Type=='put']
puts['P'] = (puts.Bid+puts.Ask)/2

df = pd.merge(calls, puts, how='inner', on ='Strike')

df

%matplotlib inline
plt.plot(df.Strike, df.P, label='Observed')
plt.plot(df.Strike,df.Parity_P, label=r'$C+ K -S_0$')
plt.xlabel('Strike')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: The problem is in the filter: `exp1 = alloptions[alloptions.Expiry == TSLA.expiry_dates[1]]`

Comment: i'd recommend some print statements in different places to see whats actually going on with the data

Answer (score 0):

If your graph is blank, here's a quick checklist to fix the issue:

1. **Check Data Retrieval**: Ensure `TSLA.get_all_data()` is pulling data. Print `alloptions` to confirm.
2. **Verify Expiry Date**: Make sure `TSLA.expiry_dates[1]` has corresponding data in `alloptions`.
3. **Ensure Non-empty Option Types**: Confirm `calls` and `puts` DataFrames aren't empty after filtering by type.
4. **Mid Price Calculation**: Check for NaN values in `Bid` and `Ask` columns which could result in NaN in the mid price calculation.
5. **Check Merge Conditions**: The merge on `Strike` could fail if there are no common strikes between calls and puts.
6. **Calculate Parity**: Your code is missing the calculation for `Parity_P`. You need to add this before plotting.

Make sure to define and calculate `Parity_P` based on the put-call parity relationship and include it in your DataFrame.

The put-call parity relationship is given by:

[image: put-call parity relationship]

where ( C ) is the call option price, ( K ) is the strike price, ( r ) is the risk-free rate, ( t ) is the time to expiration, ( P ) is the put option price, and ( S_0 ) is the current stock price.

You would need to calculate this for each option and add it to your DataFrame before plotting. Here's an example of how you might do that:

```py
r = 0.01 # Example risk-free rate
t = (exp1.Expiry - pd.Timestamp.today()).dt.days / 365 # Time to expiration in years
S_0 = web.get_data_yahoo('TSLA')['Adj Close'][-1] # Get the latest adjusted close price

# Assuming 'K' is the strike price column in your DataFrame
df['Parity_P'] = df['C'] + (df['Strike'] * np.exp(-r * t)) - S_0
```

Make sure to replace `exp1.Expiry` with the correct column name for expiration dates in your `exp1` DataFrame and `r` with the current risk-free rate. This calculation also assumes that `df` has columns named `C` and `Strike`.

Finally, you should avoid chaining assignments with pandas DataFrames (like `calls['C'] = ...`) as it can sometimes lead to a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Instead, use `.loc` for such operations:

```py
calls.loc[:, 'C'] = (calls.Bid+calls.Ask)/2
puts.loc[:, 'P'] = (puts.Bid+puts.Ask)/2
```

This should help you troubleshoot the issue and potentially fix the empty DataFrame problem.